# Can't get my Puff Pastry shells to rise

Tags: baking

I baked Pepperidge Farm Puff Pastry Shells according to what I thought were the directions.
Temperature set at 425 degrees.  I brushed the top with egg wash -- and only the top.
When they baked, there were a beautiful brown, but only 1 rose like the picture on the box.

The others were beautiful golden brown, but either flat or lop-sided.  They were cooked all the way through -- just not puffed up into a shell.

I put the pastry in the oven after I had thawed them in the refrigerator overnight.

What is my problem.  Why did only one of the shells rise??

Please Please help.....

Comment: I wrote an answer, then realized the product you are discussing is not *sheets* of puff pastry, but a preformed product.  You might want to upload a picture if you can of what went wrong so people can help.  Pepperidge Farms may also have a number on the box to call with usage questions....

Answer (score 6):

[The Pepperidge Farm](http://www.puffpastry.com/videos-and-tips#tips) site offers some tips for baking related to the rise:

- Always preheat your oven for a minimum of 15-20 minutes before baking, because Puff Pastry depends on even heat to rise and puff. Place pastries 1 inch apart.
- If you want a flaky thin and crispy pastry that's not very puffy, prick the unbaked Puff Pastry all over with a fork, which lets steam escape while baking.
- To create a tart with an extra puffy crust: take a knife and score two lines around the edge, then prick the area inside this border with a fork.

I would begin by verifying that these tips were observed. Also, I would verify that your oven bakes consistently (i.e. no hot/cold spots). Preheating can be very helpful in resolving this. Also, you can put in a pizza stone or other heat regulating product, and monitor the temperature with a probe thermometer in water in different areas of the oven.

Answer (score 1):

My mother made these for years, and I make them now, and we NEVER thaw them. We always cook them from a frozen state, and they come out fine. I've found that the only time they don't rise properly is when they're old, so check the expiration/best by date.

Answer (score 0):

If your fridge is cold then overnight may not have been long enough, and it could be that some were still frozen. I'd say that was the most likely culprit.

Comment: I think the pastry shells didnt need to be thawed prior to cooking. Pastry sheets do on the other hand.